# How can I say "the leader(s) of the club" in Japanese

Tags: word-choice

I would like to ask which one of the following two words could be used to express the word "leader" when I am talking about someone who is the head of a club or at least the member of its board; for example an anime fun club.
When I checked the dictionary I found these two words with the meaning "leader":

> 始端部`したんぶ` and 引率者`いんそつしゃ`

Comment: I would guess 会長{かいちょう} or something, if only to follow the pattern of combining the type of group with 長.

Comment: Search google images for "Suzumiya Haruhi armband" =P.

Comment: aa, I have checked it I see a screenshot showing an armband which says 団長　だんちょう。

Comment: クラブ(倶楽部)の長だから・・・ How about [部長]{ぶちょう}?

Comment: What about words with `班`?  Like `班長`, `首班`, or `主班`?  Maybe `班` gives a slightly different context, I'm not sure.

Comment: There is also リーダ, which would give the whole club a subtle foreign tang...

Answer (score 7):

I'll go ahead and add this as an answer since nobody else has, but basically you'll be taking whatever kind of gathering it is that you have, using its kanji and adding 長 to it. So for example if it's some kind of 会 then it'll be 会長. If your group is a 団, like a 劇団 or whatever, you can say 団長. If it's a school club, like in 部活動, you'll say 部長. Or as pointed out you can also just say クラブのリーダー.

[alc](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=club%20president) suggests the last two.

> club president クラブのリーダー、〔部活動の〕部長

There are other words you can explore, like 担当者, but I think the 長 route is appropriate given the context.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add, 始端部 literally means “starting end,” and is used to refer to the [leader](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_Cassette#Tape_leaders) of a magnetic tape, although I think that it is more commonly referred to as リーダー.  (But speaking of common words, magnetic tapes themselves are rare nowadays.)

It is better to always check a Japanese-English dictionary after you look up an English-Japanese dictionary.  The purpose of an English-Japanese dictionary for learners of Japanese is to list the Japanese words corresponding to many meanings of a given English word.  The purpose of a Japanese-English dictionary for learners of Japanese is to explain a given Japanese word in English.  They are not the opposite of each other.

Answer (score 1):

For a more casual setting, would not 「幹事」 be the best choice?  Some of the previous comments suggesting 部長　or 会長　seem to me to be very formal and more appropriate for business settings...

Comment: Those words can be used formally but I don't think they are exclusively reserved for business. Any kind of group with some formalized structure can have a 長, can't it?

Comment: I do not think that 幹事 is more casual (or more formal) than 部長 and 会長.